# Store output object to a dataframe from a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to write a script in R for the following equation and make dataframe for each corresponding result.

```
x<-c(1:5)
y<-c(1:5)
z<-4*(x+2*y)
```

I need to locate each result of different combination of value of X & Y, just like an excel table format with Rows/ Columns list from 1 to 5. How can I achieve by using a for loop function. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dead-set on doing this with a loop, here's a looping approach to get the same result as with `outer`:

```
result_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y))
for(i in seq(x)) {
for(j in seq(y)) {
    result_matrix[i,j] <- 4*(x[i] + 2*y[j])
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response, Dan Y!

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to use a loop, use `outer`

```
> outer(x, y, FUN=function(x,y){4*(x+2*y)})
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   12   20   28   36   44
[2,]   16   24   32   40   48
[3,]   20   28   36   44   52
[4,]   24   32   40   48   56
[5,]   28   36   44   52   60
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your alternative advice!